# Apai-io Amazon Adversting

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, apai-io

I am using Apai-IO,
Well , i finally got response but the problem that is the response is a bery long string , which i can see links in there,
how can i solve it , i know i should use the transfomer of responses , and i need to view it like XML  but i dont really understand how , i have tried

```
->setResponseTransformer(new \ApaiIO\ResponseTransformer\XmlToDomDocument());
```

but it still a long string, how can i solve it,

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: Did you solve this problem?